# stored procedure search with null value

Tags: mysql

my query for supplier_search is..

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `supplier_Search`(in strLedgerName varchar(255),in strAddress varchar(255),
       in inPhoneNo int(45),  in inMobNo int(45), in strPriceLevel varchar(255),in strCountry varchar(255),in strState varchar(255))
BEGIN
    if inPhoneNo = '' then SET inPhoneNo =Null ;end if;
    if inMobNo = '' then SET inMobNo =Null ;end if;
    if strLedgerName ='' then SET strLedgerName = Null; end if;      
    if  strAddress ='' then set strAddress = null; end if;    
    if  strPriceLevel = '' then set strPriceLevel = null; end if;
    if strCountry = '' then set strCountry = null; end if;
    if strState = '' then set strState = null; end if;
    select ledgerName,address, phoneNo , mobNo ,priceLevel,stateName, CountryName from
    (
        select joined_ab.ledgerName,joined_ab.address ,joined_ab.phoneNo, joined_ab.mobNo ,joined_ab.priceLevel,c.countryName,joined_ab.stateId
        from (select  a.ledgerName, a.address , a.phoneNo , a.mobNo ,b.priceLevel,
        a.countryId,a.stateId from tbl_ledger as a inner join tbl_price_level as b on  a.pricingLevelId =b.priceLevelId)
        as joined_ab inner join tbl_country as c on joined_ab.countryId = c.countryId
    ) as joined_abc inner join tbl_state 
    as d on joined_abc.stateId = d.stateId
    where((strLedgerName is null or joined_abc.ledgerName LIKE concat(strLedgerName,"%"))
    and(strAddress is null or address LIKE concat(strAddress ,"%"))
    and(inPhoneNo is Null or phoneNo lIke concat(inPhoneNo , "%"))
    and (strPriceLevel is null or priceLevel Like concat(strPriceLevel,"%"))      
    and(inMobNo is Null or mobNo Like concat(inMobNo , "%")) 
    and(strCountry is null or CountryName LikE concat(strCountry,"%"))
    and(strState is null or StateName LikE concat(strState,"%")));
END
```

i want to get output when one or more than one value is passed.
but the problem is when i'm not passing value for mobileNo or phoneNo and executes the error is

```
call db_account.supplier_Search('1', '', '', '', '', '', '')    
Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'inPhoneNo' at row 1   0.000 sec
```

Comment: Is it possible call thw procedure with `null` values like `call db_account.supplier_Search('1', 'null, null, null, null, null, null)`

Comment: yes it is possible. y n't?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the fact You're passing an integer value as ''.

SQL doesn't know which type of integer is; try setting 0 or NULL.

The environment is suggesting you which the issue is: you're using '' as an integer value, SQL doesn't know which type of integer is; try setting 0 or NULL. If the problem is not in the calling operation you have to change the way you compare data in the body of the procedure:

> if inPhoneNo = '' then SET inPhoneNo =Null ;end if;

Comment: is the result the same?

Comment: Excuse me, I've noticed right now that your speaking of mysql ... I filtered by sql-server.... In any case i would try to go to row 1 and change to a different value: if it is no in the caller it must be in the sp body where you compare an integer with an empty string ('')

Comment: Could you please give some more hints? Is the result the same? Which is now your query? Did you try to change the if close for all the integer to something different (example if inPhoneNo = -1 then SET inPhoneNo = Null; end if;)? Did you try to change the call statement to something like call db_account.supplier_Search('1', '', -1, -1, '', '', '')?